# Fundamental group of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

Suppose that $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. What can be said about its fundamental group? I'm sure that the answer should be well known, since this is rather natural question.

Comment: Every countable group is the fundamental group of an open subset of $\mathbb R^4$, and fundamental groups of manifolds are automatically countable, so that's a complete characterization. Fundamental groups of open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ are free. I don't know what happens in the middle dimension $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @RobArthan actually, the question has already been answered.

Comment: Here is a good text for you: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf

Comment: @RobArthan The first comment, which characterizes exactly the fundamental groups that appear in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure about $\mathbb R^4$ anymore. Sorry. I'm writing up an answer on how to do it in $\mathbb R^5$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Comments on this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19618/when-does-a-cw-complex-of-dimension-2-embedd-in-r4 claim 2-complexes with planar 1-skeleton can be embedded in $\Bbb R^4$. So one just takes an open regular neighborhood of a Cayley complex for your desired group. P.S. The first answer on that question claims this embedding is folklore.

Comment: @PVAL: Thanks, I've put that into my answer.

Answer (score 12):

The fundamental group of a (second-countable, Hausdorff) manifold is countable. See Lee, Smooth manifolds, proposition 1.16.

The fundamental group of an orientable noncompact surface (in particular an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$) is free. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces). You can realize rather easily a free group on $n$ generators or $\mathbb N$ generators as the fundamental group of a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ - just delete a discrete set of that cardinality. This is a complete characterization.

The fundamental group of an open subset of $\mathbb R^5$ can be whatever you like. Here's a construction. Pick a countable presentation of your group $\langle w_1, w_2, \dots \mid r_1, r_2, \dots \rangle$. Take a 5-ball centered at the origin; attach [1-handles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_decomposition) for each $w_i$. (This will be a manifold with boundary, but not a compact one - the handles will head out to infinity. This manifold looks like what you get when you take a circle of radius 1, glue another on to the rightmost point, glue another on to the rightmost point, etc, out to infinity, and take a tubular neighborhood. Think about what happens in $\mathbb R^3$ for inspiration on this picture.) Call this $\Sigma_0$. Inductively suppose we have the manifold $\Sigma_i \subset \mathbb R^5$. Pick a loop in the boundary of $\Sigma_i$ representing $r_i$; by a version of the Whitney embedding theorem, this bounds a disc in $\mathbb R^5 \setminus \text{int} \Sigma_i$. Call a small neighborhood of this disc $D_i$. Let $\Sigma_{i+1} = \Sigma_i \cup D_i$; this has killed $r_i$. Now take the limit of these (with care!) to get $\Sigma_\infty$, a 5-manifold with boundary with desired fundamental group in $\mathbb R^5$. Now delete the boundary.

What I've done here is a more straightforward way of picturing taking an embedding of a 2-dimensional CW complex into $\mathbb R^5$ and taking a regular neighborhood. Because you can give a 2-dimensional CW complex whatever fundamental group, you're done. PVAL assures me in the comments to the question that you can embed a 2-dimensional CW complex with planar 1-skeleton into $\mathbb R^4$, so that pushes the result down one dimension (because you can realize any countable group as the fundamental group of such a thing), but that this is a folklore result (that is, not written down anywhere). See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19618/when-does-a-cw-complex-of-dimension-2-embedd-in-r4).

It remains to say something about $\mathbb R^3$. Here's one obstruction. If a finitely generated group is the fundamental group of a noncompact 3-manifold $N$, then there is a compact 3-manifold $M \subset N$ such that $\pi_1(M) \to \pi_1(N)$ is an isomorphism. This is known as Scott's Compact Core theorem. In particular $G = \pi_1(M)$, and thus $G$ is finitely presented. So the fundamental group cannot be finitely generated but not finitely presented. An example is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/547144/98602).

Comment: For $\Bbb R^3$ I thought $H_1$ torsion-free would be an obstruction (It is true say for complements of CW-complexes or manifolds by Alexander duality). Apparently in general that is open : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4478/torsion-in-homology-or-fundamental-group-of-subsets-of-euclidean-3-space .

Comment: @PVAL: That's horrible. Yikes. (I've added an obstruction: if the group is finitely generated, it has to be finitely generated.)

Comment: Also, arbitrary 2-complexes cannot be embedded into $\Bbb R^4$. In the question I linked the 2-skeleton of the 6-simplex is an example as it would lead to an unlinked embedding of the 1-skeleton in $\Bbb R^3$. The supposed folklore theorem is that it works for 2-complexes with planar 1-skeleton (i.e. cayley complexes).

Comment: oh, ok. Fixed the misstatement in my answer. Luckily as you say we don't need every 2-complex, just enough to get every countable group. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @PVAL: Actually [this comment](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4478/torsion-in-homology-or-fundamental-group-of-subsets-of-euclidean-3-space?rq=1#comment4795_4482) on that question provides a proof that $H_1$ is torsion-free for open subsets of $\Bbb R^3$.